# Retain drop-down list values in PHP without using array

Tags: php, html

I have a drop-down list containing all the countries in the world. The first few countries are:

```
Country: <select name="Country">
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
</select>
```

Forming an array would require over 200 elements. Is there a way to retain the drop-down value in PHP after a form post without using an array? Thank you.

Comment: What are your reasons against using an array?

Comment: I would need to create the array, which would take very long considering the number of countries.

Comment: I am confused.... what do you mean by retain the value?

Comment: after a form post in PHP, there will be only one value: $_GET["Country"] or $_POST["Country"].

Comment: can you explain more by just showing what you would do with an array to get whatever you want done?  just so we can understand what you're trying to do exactly and help find a way around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really are best using an array, it won't take any real noticable time to iterate through 200 items

Something like this should keep the selected item after post

```
<select name="country" method="POST">
<?php

for($i=0;$i<count($countries);$i++)
   {
   $selected="";

   if($countries[$i]==$_POST['country'])
      {
      $selected="selected";
      }

   ?><option <?php echo $selected;?> value="<?php echo $countries[$i];?>"><?php echo $countries[$i];?></option><?php
   }
?>
</select>
```